# How to config postgresql to not to log actual data that is inserted in database?

Tags: postgresql, logging, reporting

I have enabled logging in my PostgreSQL.conf Currently my config as follows

```
log_directory = ''
log_filename = '' 
log_min_messages = info 
log_min_error_statement = error 
log_min_duration_statement = -1 
log_checkpoints = on 
log_connections = on 
log_disconnections = on 
log_duration = on 
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p-%l] %q%u@%d '
log_statement = 'all'
```

currently logs are being generated but the sensitive data is being logged as well. how do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

The database server log is considered safe. By default, only the database administrators and superusers can read it.

If you are trying to keep the contents of the database from the database administrators, that is going to be difficult (I would say impossible).

Comment: In the unlikely event @LaurenceAlbe in incorrect and you can hide it from the database administrator I will suggest you don't actually want to. Since sensitive data tends to also be important data the first data problem that cannot be resolved because of it will tell you why.

Comment: @Belayer if it is possible to hide the data. can you please tell me how to do so???

Comment: If you don't want the statements in the log, don't set `log_statement = 'all'`.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to hide data from the DBA is generally a lost cause, unless you encrypt it before sending it to the database.  And no one else (or at least no untrusted people) should have access to the database log files.

But, you can reduce the "surface area" of logged parameters by setting `log_error_verbosity = terse`.  That will only work if you send the data in extended or prepared statements, rather than hard-coded into the query text.  This can be hard to guarantee, as whatever connection library you use might circumvent your efforts do do that.